# How can I use Google App Script to execute similar function in many rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Following is the script I had created:

```
function recordValue() {
  //read the current trigger price in 'Set Alert'!G2 and record it in cell P2
  var triggerPrice = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Set Alerts").getRange('G2').getCell(1, 1).getValue();
  var outputCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Set Alerts").getRange('P2').getCell(1, 1);
  if (triggerPrice != "") {
  outputCell.setValue(triggerPrice);
}
}
```

The above script is only executable in row 2 but I want to execute this code in further rows (3, 4, 5, 6, 7......11). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Loop,

```
     function recordValue() {
      //read the current trigger price in 'Set Alert'!G2 and record it in cell P2
      for(var rowIndex = 1 ; rowIndex < 11 ; rowIndex++) {
         var triggerPrice =   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Set Alerts").getRange('G2').getCell(rowIndex, rowIndex).getValue();
         var outputCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Set Alerts").getRange('P2').getCell(rowIndex, rowIndex);
         if (triggerPrice != "") {
             outputCell.setValue(triggerPrice);
         }
      }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Nitin. Appreciated your efforts. However, I'm a complete beginner so I'm not able to understand the script. Can you explain, how it's working? How it's reading the value? What's the workflow? It will be very much helpful.